# UITextField: backspace not working

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have an issue with `UITextField`'s validation. I want to validate the `UITextField's` text-length to be 5(fixed).

my code :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField==codeTxt)
    {
         NSCharacterSet *unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS]invertedSet] ;

         if ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unacceptedInput] count] > 1)
            return NO;

        else if ([codeTxt.text length] >= 5])
            return NO;

        else
            return YES;
    }
}
```

this code works fine. It validates and ignores rest of the text(more thn 5).

my problem :
When I press Delete(Backspace), nothing happens !!! the text remains the same. delete(Backspace) does not work.

what could be the problem ?

Thanks...

Comment: In your NUMBERS you have to include backspace character also then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField==codeTxt)
    {

        NSCharacterSet *unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS]invertedSet] ;
        NSLog(@"textfield character validation method called");


        NSLog(@"%d",[codeTxt.text length]);

        if ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unacceptedInput] count] > 1)
            return NO;

        else if ([codeTxt.text length] >= 5 && ![string isEqual:@""])
            return NO;

        else
            return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

put this condition at first statement in shouldChangeCharactersInRange method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([string length]==0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if(textField==codeTxt)
    {
         NSCharacterSet *unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS]invertedSet] ;

         if ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unacceptedInput] count] > 1)
            return NO;

        else if ([codeTxt.text length] >= 5])
            return NO;

        else
            return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you write like above it will work fine.same code working fine in my case

Comment: does my keyboard type matters ?

Answer (score 1):

Your only checking the length of the current text in the field.  This method gets called before the text changes, so you need to check the `replacementString`'s length first, then check the `textField`'s text length.

**Try this:**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField == codeTxt) {
         // NSCharacterSet *unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS] invertedSet];
         // if ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[unacceptedInput count]] > 1) {
         if ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS] invertedSet] autorelease]] count] > 1) {
            return NO;
        } else if ([string length] < 5) {
             return YES;
        } else if ([codeTxt.text length] >= 5]) {
            return NO;
        } else {
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edit:

<strike>Checking the `textField`'s length probably isn't even necessary after doing `[codeTxt.text length] >= 5]` since this will prevent the `textField`'s length from ever going above 4 anyway.</strike>

Actually, you would need to check it since the default is to `return YES;`.

---

Probably needs to be <= 5

```
        } else if ([string length] <= 5) {
             return YES;
        }
```

Instead of < 5 too

```
        } else if ([string length] < 5) {
             return YES;
        }
```